# Wordpress template hierarchy for a custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, wordpress-theming

I'm using [Types](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/types) plugin for create a Wordpress Custom Post Type (CPT), now I need to customize the archive page for that CPT and also the category page and I'm asking **how do I achieve this?** I've read [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/9/96/wp-template-hierarchy.jpg) docs from Wordpress Codex site about the template hierarchy but is not clear to me at all how many templates I should create and how should be named.

Let me explain now what I have done: the CPT is called `legislaciones` and have create a page called `category-legislaciones.php` that file works for a URL like `/category/legislaciones/` but what about the archive? what about the result on this URL `/category/legislaciones/legislacion-1-ley`? How do I customize that pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For archive page you have to create taxonomy page for CPT category by
>   naming like

```
taxonomy-legislaciones.php
```

Comment: And what about the page itself? How do I customize that template?

Answer (score 1):

For a custom taxonomy named legislaciones (p.s. you may have issues with a capitalized slug), per the Template Hierarchy, the taxonomy archive index template file is taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php, or taxonomy-legislaciones.php

For a custom post type named like books (p.s. you may have issues with a capitalized slug), per the Template Hierarchy, the post archive index template file is single-{post_type}.php, or single-books.php.